# cordova googlep plus login return only email of the user

Tags: cordova, npm, google-api, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

cordova googlep plus login returns only the email of the user.
But I want all values that are mentioned in the documentation.
like

```
obj.email         
obj.userId        
obj.displayName  
obj.imageUrl      
obj.idToken        
obj.serverAuthCode
```

I'm using demo code of npm.
   [See Here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/demo/index.html)

Please show me what's going wrong. I have tried lots of thing like reconfigure keytool by SHA1 and recreate app in google developer console with android and also web application. But the problem is the same.

Comment: Please show a code example of your actual problem.

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the code you have written so far? [We need a MCVE before we can help!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have used demo code. [see here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/demo/index.html)